# How to show a alertDialog with a NumberPicker inside a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog, numberpicker

I'm trying to get a value with a numberpicker that appears when user click (**just one click**) inside a EditText. 
However Im getting some doubts on:
 1) What method should I call when user click on EditText field
 2) How I declare a AlertDialog (using Builder) to prompt when user calls method in **1)**.

I appreciate any kind of ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a layout with your number picker, or whatever UI you want in it, then create your dialog like this:

```
View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);

new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
    .setView(view)
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
    .setTitle("My Dialog")
    .create()
    .show();
```

Where my_layout is your custom layout.

Comment: That's what I am doing. However I'm getting some problems on appliance of this. Basically, this alertDialog will called when methods like OnFocusChangeListener() or  OnTouchListener() of an EditText are called. But I'm having some problems with that. When OnFocusChangeListener() it's used other EditText fields create this AlertDialog and OnTouchListener() make me some problems to dismiss the AlertDialog (I need to click two or more times to dismiss it).

Comment: If you use Alert dialog to input value, u will no need default android softkeyboard appear, right? So, disable  editable action of EditText, just use OnClickListener event

Comment: @HugoFonseca Thats interesting, but none of that was even mentioned in your question. I answered the question you posted.

Comment: Yes GregEnnis, you're right. Besides I already did it, thanks both of you @DanhDC and GregEnnis.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate method and call it in the "OnClickListener" method that you implement in your EditText. I did the following:

```
public void numberPicker(){
    final NumberPicker numberPicker = new NumberPicker(getActivity());
    numberPicker.setMaxValue(360); //Maximum value to select
    numberPicker.setMinValue(0); //Minimum value to select


    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setView(numberPicker);
    builder.setTitle("Number picker");
    builder.setMessage("Choose a value :");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Number selected "+numberPicker.getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You have not selected anything", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

Instead of a toast you can use setText () to fill in the text field you want.